# Is there a small and clean jQuery-like library that focuses only on HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, zepto

jQuery can do some nice things for you. It also frees you from having to take care for different browsers. The tradeoffs are the **size** and **readability** jQuery's own code.

Is there a similar library that purely relies on the new HTML5 APIs like `draggable`, `querySelector`, `postMessage`, etc. ? It should support jQuery's basic stuff, such as querying, basic animation, drag&drop, xhr, etc.

Thx,
Juve

**[Edit]** 9muses proposed [zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto), which might be a good starting point.

Comment: JQuery has 30kb when minified. So thats not a reason against using it.

Comment: Yes, that is not much, but zepto is like 2-5k. The other reasons are readability of code and checking for HTML5 compatibility. I am mainly using HTML5/JS/SVG for explorative prototyping and I also want to see how far the browser vendors have implemented the HTML5 APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto), might be something for you.

Comment: In was also thinking primarily of zepto, even if it is a bit webkit specific. Let's see if somebody else comes up with another proposal.

Comment: To bring this discussion up to date. Zepto is approaching 1.0 and added support for all major browsers, although the browsers themselves don't fully support Zepto's approach yet. For example there is now a `-ms` prefix for animations, but until IE supports the corresponding CSS3 properties it won't work obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen one that looks at those features specifically but you might find something here: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/html5